# Clickable link into the div via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamic HTML structure. Like this:

```
 <div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum http://google.com dolour sit
 amet<br>&nbsp;</div>
```

I want click this `http` link and other all links.

How can I find it and make clickable via jQuery?

Comment: what you mean with "make clickable via jquery"???
You can add an id to the div and use $('#idDiv').click(...) to catch the click event

Comment: Put the link in the <a> tag

Comment: Wrap the url inside a `<a>` tag then handle click using event delegation on the div see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data)

Comment: I cannot put <a> tag, this HTML is dynamic!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you could use a normal hyperlink:

```
<div class="message-text">Lorem ipsum<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> dolour sit amet<br>&nbsp;</div>
```

If for whatever reason that is not in option, you could try javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Lorem ipsum http://google.com dolour sit
 amet<br>&nbsp;");
a.appendChild(http://google.com);
a.href = "http://google.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

I hope this helps you at all!

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to dynamically replace plain text URLs to clickable URLs (its HTML representation) there is a quite good discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exhaustive answer, but it may get you started.  You have to take the text, turn it into a url then put it back.  Here is how. And here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Psh2V/1/).

```
$(function(){
    var newStr;
   var matchStr=$("div.message-text").html();
   var REGEX_MATCHER_URL = LINK_DETECTION_REGEX = /(([a-z]+:\/\/)?(([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|travel|local|internal))(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/[a-z0-9_\-\.~]+)*(\/([a-z0-9_\-\.]*)(\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)(\s+|$)/gi

   $("div.message-text").each(function(index, div){
     var newDiv;
     var oldDiv;
     var oldTextArray;
     var oldDivHtml = $(div).html();
     $(div).html(""); // clear it

     var matches = oldDivHtml.match(REGEX_MATCHER_URL);
     $.each(matches, function(index, value){
       var holder = oldDivHtml.split(value);
       $(div).append(holder[0]);
       $(div).append($("<a>").attr("href", value).html(value));
       $(div).append(' ' + holder[1]);
     });
   });

});
```